# How can one create a Genesis Block for a new Proof of Stake Cryptocurrency?

Tags: proof-of-stake, genesis-block, altcoin-development

I've been trying to fork the cryptocurrency Clams for about a week now. All of my code is correct to the coin's specifications, but I've been stuck on the creation of the blockchain. The developers have removed the code involving the genesis block and there doesn't seem to be any way for me to generate the PoS genesis block. If anyone has any experience with PoS coins, I would appreciate any advice incredibly. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know all of your code is correct?

Comment: What would it mean to have a valid PoS genesis block? What would you even be proving stake of?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution?  Use their own initial hash.

Comment: Will this mean that the client might accidentally download the other blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

how to To create a genesis block

`Main.h`

Delete Both Main Merkle & Genesis Merkle (example)
Main genesis block

```
static const uint256 hashGenesisBlock("0x000004611c87517dfd29fe7f34bd6da2e1ad3d305ac12afe80a3229069390f68");
```

To

```
static const uint256 hashGenesisBlock("");
```

---

and inside `Main.h` too
Testnet Genesis

```
static const uint256 hashGenesisBlockTestNet("0x000004611c87517dfd29fe7f34bd6da2e1ad3d305ac12afe80a3229069390f68");
```

To

```
static const uint256 hashGenesisBlockTestNet("");
```

---

inside `Main.cpp` 
Change this to your Timestamp wanted
(Example)

```
const char* pszTimestamp = "Blockchain.info Block #312427 2014-07-25 14:15:16";
```

---

inside: `Main.cpp`
Change these both to your Epoch Time wanted  //Unixtime check google

```
txNew.nTime = 1406297716;  (example) (example) 
block.nTime    = 1406297716;  (example) (example) (example)
```

---

inside: `Main.cpp`
Change these to 0

```
block.nNonce   = !fTestNet ? 190271 : 190271;   (example) (example) (example)
```

---

inside: `Main.cpp`
Change this to say true

```
if (false && (block.GetHash() != hashGenesisBlock))
```

into

```
if (true && (block.GetHash() != hashGenesisBlock))
```

---

inside: `Main.cpp`
Delete the Merkle root

```
assert(block.hashMerkleRoot == uint256("0xc9c8f6250a60dc79038b9ae68ff747488ac80d4a2db0b194cf49628495448d21"));
```

To

```
assert(block.hashMerkleRoot == uint256(""));
```

---

Now Compile the Wallet, and let it crash. 
as next you find on the debug file the Merkle Root/Hash
replace it into the blank space from you step before.
but make sure that you have to add to the beginning 0x
just compare and undo the steps with the new infos.

---

Save the Main.cpp with the New `hashMerkleRoot` added by you.
and recompile. then start again and let the wallet crash 
one more time like before.  visit again the debug log 
and replace other infos.

you find in the debug `block.nNonce`  you remind that you remove that before. 
and the Genesis/Block Hash .. you remind you delete this as first.
copy and paste into the free space inside the Main.h and add 0x on the beginning too.

---

That's it. Save all files and compile one more time.
and you are a Coin Developer :-)

Comment: I have followed this example and got stuck with the following error -> ERROR: CTxDB::LoadBlockIndex() : Failed stake modifier checkpoint height=0 <- described in details in a separate question ->  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61384/altcoin-debug-log-shows-error-ctxdbloadblockindex-failed-stake-modifier-c - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get original blockchain (curracy that you fork) and read genesis block. Then you can see what happens there and maybe you will find bug in the code faster.